# Grid of divs that are size of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a grid of divs that are the size of the viewport. Just to set a few basic variables, lets say I want it to be 7 divs wide and 10 divs high.

Here is a code I have so far to set the div size:

```
function height() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    height = parseInt(height) + 'px';
    $(".page").css('height',height);
}
    $(document).ready(function() {
        height();
        $(window).bind('resize', height);
});

function width() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    width = parseInt(width) + 'px';
    $(".page").css('width',width);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    width();
    $(window).bind('width', width);
});
```

Right now I just have 2 divs that are stacked on top of each other. One is red and one is black, just so I can see them. I want to be able to put content inside the divs. I also made sure to put

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Later I am going to put some scrolling features with jQuery but for now I just want a way to make the grid.

**Edit:**
Each individual div is the size of the viewport

**Edit:**
I used ***[this](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)*** handy plugin for the scrolling that is much better then a small script at the end of the page

Comment: I guess you want a grid of 10 columns and 7 rows that stretch up to the entire screen. Is it right? Please make it clear. Also create a jsfiddle of what you have tried as of now

Comment: Ya, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't need any javascript for this as it can be easier achieved with just CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content1">
  Place your content here.
</div>
<div id="content2">
  Place your content here.
</div>
<div id="content3">
  Place your content here.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#content1,#content2,#content3 {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important; /*min-height hack*/
  height: 100%;            /*min-height hack*/
}
```

**[EXAMPLE 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/C739b/)**

All 3 divs have the size of the browser window and of course they adjust accordingly. Also you can add a anchor link to navigate from tab to tab with again just html/css

```
<a href="#content1">Go to Main Element</a>
```

If a navigation like this is something you would like to have then you can have a look on the

**[EXAMPLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/C739b/1/)**

PS: in the example i have separated the css of the boxes just to put different colors but you can have it as i posted it above.

I've also created another fiddle for you, as my first two versions were missing something...You asked for a couple of divs vertically and a couple horizontally.

**[EXAMPLE 3](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/9Y4B5/)**

This example has 3x2 divs (6 total) but with the same logic you can make them 7x10.
Please don't hesitate to ask if you don't understand anything in the code.

Also i've added a bit of jQuery to make the scrolling more smooth, which is optional, you can just remove it

**JavaScript** (don't forget to include jQuery)

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function () {

    $root.animate({

        scrollLeft: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().left,
       scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top

    }, 500);

    return false;
});
```

Hope this helps you

EDIT: You need to include jQuery in your code and also wrap the javascript code with:

```
$(window).load(function(){

});
```

Comment: This js is rad. The only problem with this whole idea is that it all falls apart if you change the viewport size. Maybe it is a good idea to do the math with js and a listener? I don't know much about how expensive that is though, as far as adding to the browsers workload.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to combine yours and the CSS made by sheriffderek

Comment: I actually realized a problem. I want to be able to add rows and columns without screwing up the order of all the divs. My site is a project site and I want the categories to be the columns and the projects to run down those rows. Don't worry, I will cycle out projects to an archive so the page doesn't get packed.

Comment: I am having trouble, your javascript doesn't work outside of JSFiddle.

Comment: Check my last edit on my answer. You need to run the code on page load and also include the jquery library.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell if you want the div to be the entire size of the screen and then have the overflow scroll - and shoot over to the next panel, or if you want your grid of divs to be the size of the viewport. If it's the second, here is my answer.

[fiddle is here:](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/cRxf7/)

### HTML

```
<div class="block">01</div>
<div class="block">02</div>
<div class="block">03</div>
<div class="block">04</div>
<div class="block">05</div>
<div class="block">06</div>
<div class="block">07</div>
<div class="block">etc. (to 70)</div>
```

### CSS

```
* { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ */
    margin: 0;
} 

html {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.block {
    width: 14.285714%%; /* 100/7 */
    float: left;
    height: 10%; /* 100/10 */
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

#### Now, If that's not what you wanted, maybe this is.

[fiddle is here:](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/S28ez/)

### HTML

```
<div id="content1" class="block">
    <h2>block 01</h2>
</div>

<div id="content2" class="block">
    <h2>block 02</h2>
</div>

<div id="content3" class="block">
    <h2>block 03</h2>
</div>

<div id="content4" class="block">
    <h2>block 04</h2>
</div>

<div id="content5" class="block">
    <h2>block 05</h2>
</div>

<div id="content6" class="block">
    <h2>block 06</h2>
</div>

<div id="content7" class="block">
    <h2>block 07</h2>
</div>

<div id="content8" class="block">
    <h2>block 08</h2>
</div>

<!-- you'll need 70... ? -->

<nav class="global-nav">
    <a href="#content1">01</a>
    <a href="#content2">02</a>
    <a href="#content3">03</a>
    <a href="#content4">04</a>
    <a href="#content5">05</a>
    <a href="#content6">06</a>
    <a href="#content7">07</a>
    <a href="#content8">08</a>
</nav>
```

### CSS ( a little SASS in here for quickness )

```
* { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
    width: 700%;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    /*This would hide the scroll bars but I'm leaving them for you to see */
}

.block {
     min-height: 100%;
     height: auto !important; /*min-height hack*/
     height: 100%;            /*min-height hack*/

     width: 100%/7;  /* SASS division to be quick*/
     float: left;
     border: 1px solid red;
}

.global-nav {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.global-nav a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to combine your CSS with the jQuery from Thanos

Comment: I actually realized a problem. I want to be able to add rows and columns without screwing up the order of all the divs. My site is a project site and I want the categories to be the columns and the projects to run down those rows. Don't worry, I will cycle out projects to an archive so the page doesn't get packed.

Comment: If they are in blocks, like php WordPress etc -- it should stack up just fine floating left etc

Comment: Ya, I fixed it. I may have been able to do it better but I just used the third example from the answer above with the clear div.

Comment: I thought this idea was pretty cool and used @Thanos's js to make this codepen yesterday.   http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/uHkGd  Pretty neat.

Comment: Ya, I was thinking of a nice design for my site and this popped into my head. I will edit a link in when I am done with it.

Comment: Cool. I'd love to see it. I have to say though - as far as responsive, its a mess it the user changes the viewport size.

Comment: Maybe I can use my old viewport script to detect it, wait a few seconds, then reload the page