# <div> to the right is pushed lower by the content of the left <div>

Tags: html, css

[Demo of Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/b2550/9Y4B5/7/)
[Kind of Solved Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/b2550/9Y4B5/8/)

*It is only kind of solved because I want to be able to have divs with different sized content*

**Edit:**
Now what I need is a way to make it so these divs don't interact like this while behaving the same way

**First, an image:**
[image: Reference Image]

**And now some code:**

So I have two divs that are positioned next to each other with this CSS:

```
.horizontal {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
```

The div on the left has a spacer with this:

```
.tspacer {
width:100%;
height:110px;
```

It then has an iFrame, this is the HTML for the left div:

```
<div id="home" class="horizontal" style="font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;">
<center><img src="img/light.png" class="home-light" /></center>
<div class="tspacer"></div>
<iframe src="iframe/home_slider.html" width="100%" height="300px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

And the div on the right just has some text:

```
<div id="ent" class="horizontal" style="background-color:#F00">
Entertainment
</div>
```

**Finally, what the heck I need:**

I need to make the entertainment div snap to the top of the page. This page contains a grid of divs ([Click here for more on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177236/grid-of-divs-that-are-size-of-viewport)) and for some reason all the other divs in the next rows and columns are being pushed down by the content of the first (I think) The thing that confuses me is that the slider has a shadow inside the iframe and the right div seems to start in the middle of that. Anyway, why wont they line up in a normal, not offset, grid.

Comment: can you post a fiddle that reproduces the problem or link us to your site?

Comment: So here is what was wrong, lets say the divs are floating in water and the content is air. If the div only has content at the top, only the top will be above water level (bottom of the left div) and as more content is added, the divs will evan out. So you need to add a spacer div over the content that is the right size of all of the divs. So I am going to attempt to size the inner div to the size of the outer div . If I need scrolling content I will make a special sized div. I also may revert of old javascript to resize the div for some aspects. Click on the link above to find that javascript.

Comment: I will make that the answer if it works

Comment: OK, so the thing I posted above is what is happening. How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure of what you need, but have you tried setting `vertical-align:top` to your `.horizontal` class like this http://jsfiddle.net/9Y4B5/15/embedded/result/

Comment: @koala_dev To spite the fact that you have almost no idea what I want you nailed it! Thanks! Please answer with this so I can give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're missing `vertical-align:top` in your `.horizontal` class

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y4B5/15/embedded/result/)**

Answer (score 0):

try using `float:left` and `float:right` instead of `display:inline-block`

Comment: No, that destroys the page. I gets rid of the horizontal positioning so all the divs are aligned down the page.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the width:

```
.horizontal{ width:50%; }
```

assuming you want 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/9Y4B5/12/)

There are 2 things that need to be modified.

1) The CSS (`p` was causing the spacing issue since it was set to `block`)

```css
p {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

2) The HTML (just remove the spaces between the `div`s

```html
</div><div...
<!-- no space above -->
```

Comment: No, that is not what I am looking for, sorry.

Comment: Can you explain from my Fiddle what you are looking to see?